# SSIS Truncate/Delete all rows and Reinsert versus Insert/Update the delta

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, data-migration

I need to write a SSIS package to import data from approximately 1400 tables each containing several millions of records from Oracle to SQL Server every after 15 days. Which approach is recommended:

At every import, foreach table in SQL Server

- Truncate/Delete all records, and import all records from Oracle
- Foreach row in each table in SQL Server, check if it's updated in corresponding Oracle table, if so, update it, and insert new rows if any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say it depends on the size of delta. If changes are going to be significant, go with truncate; otherwise update.

Comment: Gosh, 1400 tables ! Are they all similar or do they have common features? How on earth will you write scripts for this many?

Comment: @Gosh: No, they donot have anything in common. I am thinking to use a `foreach` loop and use `SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: How easy is it to detect change? Do you have a simple metric, like a last modified date or some other flag or will you need to basically do a field to field comparison? Do you need to account for deletes in the source system? What is your SLA for getting the data copied over? What version (2005/2008/2012) and edition (standard, enterprise, BI, etc) of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @billinkc: a) I will have to do a field comparison, b) I also need to monitor deletes, c) I am not quite clear with the term 'SLA', d) versions: SQL Server 2012 and Oracle 11g.

Comment: Does the destination need to retain the deleted records, those no longer found in the source?  How much data are you talking about, GBs, TBs, PBs?

Answer (score 2):

Ever considered using [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=28766) ?

Comment: Yes, I have used SSMA for migrating database schema, but I am not sure whether it's the best option for periodic data import.

Comment: I do agree that for automation, it's not the best tool. But, you can import a complete schema (1400 tables, in your case?) with a simple click. I do believe it better than developing and maintaining an ETL for those 1400 tables, unless you are pretty damn sure they won't change over time.